# Can I send byte by Ruby socket?

Tags: ruby, sockets, byte

generally, we can send byte in C or C++ socket program, so I want to know can i do this in Ruby?

Comment: A good idea would be to show the code you use for this in C / C++.

Comment: Do you want to send only a byte, or do you want to send data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the Ruby standard library has general support for [socket programming](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/socket/rdoc/index.html); specifically, see the [Socket.tcp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/socket/rdoc/classes/Socket.html#M003747) method for connecting to a host and sending a byte.  For example:

```
require 'socket'
Socket.tcp('127.0.0.1', 9999) do |sock|
  sock.send(255.chr, 0) # Send the byte 0xff.
  sock.recv(1) # Read a byte from the remote host.
end # Socket is closed upon exiting the block.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do something like. Open a connection, and send some data constructed in bits and bytes via it. You can do that in ruby.

Take a look at this [source file](https://github.com/jpoz/APNS/blob/master/lib/apns/core.rb) from a ruby gem called APNS as a example of how to do it. In the given file, they are sending a push notification(s) through a socket which connects to Apple's APNS.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has a [Socket](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/socket/1.9.2/frames) library, plus [Net](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/net/1.9.2/frames) libraries for higher level communications.

The online version of Programming Ruby has an [overview of the network and web libraries](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/lib_network.html).

They all have sample code